# WINE and items in notification area

Tags: wine, dropbox

I have an app called Dropbox. I installed it with the help of WINE. Well, I get the icon in the Ubuntu notification area, but when I click on it to open it, it is transparent (see attached image)

[image]

Comment: Quick question: Why didn't you install the Ubuntu Dropbox version? https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Comment: There is a Dropbox Linux native client. You do not need to install it via Wine :/

Comment: [I think we should reopen this.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/4165/22949)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you installed the Windows version of Dropbox (there's no logical reason that comes to mind), but you can install the Ubuntu version easily.

- First, go to https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx.
- You will get a page like this:
  [image: Page]
  You will see that I highlighted the Ubuntu version. Download the file that fits your architecture.
- You can find out which architecture you have by opening Gnome-System Monitor.
  [image: Gnome-System-Monitor]
- To install Dropbox, just double click on the .deb file that you downloaded, and click install when Ubuntu Software Center opens.
- When prompted, enter your password.
- From here on, Dropbox will be installed on your system and kept up to date via the update manager.

Comment: I know about the Dropbox.com app. Actually, what I'm having issues with is also called DropBox, but it's from dropshots.com.

Comment: @Nathan: Why didn't you say that in your question?

Comment: Ok, it seems the latest version of Play on Linux was not installed (4.0 is the latest in Software Center). During the 4.1.7 upgrade it installed some WINE elements and the window appears normal now. http://a.yfrog.com/img222/3417/2w1.png

Comment: @Nathan still... when you are referring to an application that is likely to be mixed up with another, be specific.